# I believe I was overcharged. Does the taxi meter always show units of local currency, particularly in Bosnia and Herzegovina? (Convertable Marks)

Tags: taxis, corruption

The taxi meter showed "11.60" at destination. Yet the driver charged me 30 convertible mark (BAM / KM). Should I have been charged 11.60 KM? The ride was between 21:53 and 22:07 on a Wednesday night, it was not more than 6.8 km long, starting outside Bihac into the center of Bihac, with Gradski Taxi, which I believe has 1 km=1 KM (06:00-22:00) written on the side of its taxis.

Comment: That's the main reason why I use ride shares and avoid taxis like the plague. I've been cheated by taxi drivers more than I care to count but only once by a ride share driver (and that was quickly resolved).

Comment: @Hilmar I am not sure a ride share service such as blablacar would be frequent enough or have enough coverage for my purposes sadly, which are usually to cover the last leg of my trip if I'm late for check-in at a hostel. I wonder if one solution might be to take a photograph of the numberplate before getting in the taxi and to take a photo of the meter before talking about payment.

Comment: @novice I believe Hilmar was thinking more about services like Uber, Lyft, Bolt, etc. (don’t know which, if any, operate in that area though)

Comment: If anybody knows of a service similar to Uber in Bosnia I would be grateful for the information to be honest.

Comment: Did the driver say why he was charging 30 marks?  Did you ask why the charge was 30 marks when the meter showed 11.60?  In my experience in Sarajevo, some of the meters are (or used to be) nominally denominated in euros, because (I assume) they are second-hand equipment from Germany or Austria, but despite the presence of a euro symbol, they are calibrated to show the fare in BAM.

Comment: @phoog I gave him a 50KM note, and he only gave me a 10KM note and two 5KM coins change (I did say something like 'Is that correct?' and he communicated it was). I did not see a euro symbol on the meter, but I believe I tapped on the thing and asked it it was denominated in euro (he laughed and said no). If he really wanted to explain he could have used Google Translate (I had been using this and the voice input function during the ride to speak to him in Bosnian once or twice), but instead he gave the impression his german language proficiency was holding him back from explaining.

Comment: I thought it was too difficult to challenge him further because it was after 10pm, so normal fares no longer apply. But at this price going forward taxi wouldn't really make sense for me, I may as be walking another hour and checking in late.

Comment: @novice: I meant Ride Share like Uber, Lyft, Didi, Grab Car, Scoot, etc. Some version of them is available in most countries  but availability does indeed vary sometimes even from city to city. I don't know about our specific location. You probably DID get cheated by the taxi driver. Unfortunately that's very common especially for foreign passengers.  Best you can do is to make a show of taking a photo of the taxi license if it's displayed the car. This is the best way of communicating: "I know you name and you number, I can follow up".

Answer (score 2):

You were scammed.

Taxi tariffs in Bosnia are usually somewhere in the range KM 1.00 to 1.50 per km and an initial fee of KM 2-3. Tariffs may be a bit higher during the night, but KM 11.60 sounds like a correct price for a 7km ride.

I have never been to a country where taxi meters do not show the local currency and there is no reason to believe that they don't in Bosnia. Even if the meter had shown €11.60, that should have been around KM 23 and not KM 30 as you were charged.

Comment: If I was scammed, I would like to know how to make a report to the relevant local, national, or international body tackling corruption, or authorities such as the local police and business standards regulator. I would not like it to result in a time-consuming court case, however I would like to deter taxi drivers from behaving in this way or encourage the taxi company to tell drivers explicitly that they cannot overcharge tourists.

Comment: @novice Without being very familiar with the situation in Bosnia and Herzegovina, I would assume that the police and the regulating authority is corrupt. A complaint will have absolutely no effect. The only way to prevent being a victim of scams or fall into a corruption trap is to not go to countries where this is an issue. You could of course have paid the taxi driver what you owe him and then left. He would not likely have called the police on you for not paying the money he is trying to scam you for.

Comment: The suggested solution could only be possible if you have that exact change. Give a driver a 50€ note, and he gives back only a 20 euros, what does a lone traveller do at night? Start an argument? Threaten to denounce the driver... maybe that might have some effect but only if you are not travelling alone.